# Acro Package - Customise the \printacronyms style with hyphen or other

Tags: koma-script, hyphenation, acronyms, acro

I am trying to write a `List of Acronyms` and I am trying to work out how to edit the output format of the `\printacronyms` lists. The way I would like them to look is as below, it is not essential that the spacing be exactly as shown below but that is the general idea.

Please find below an MWE for your convenience, thank you

[image: Hyphenated style]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{acro}

% probably a good idea for the nomenclature entries:
%\acsetup{first-style=long}

% class `abbrev': abbreviations:
\DeclareAcronym{ny}{
  short = NY ,
  long  = New York ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{la}{
  short = LA ,
  long  = Los Angeles ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{un}{
  short = UN ,
  long  = United Nations ,
  class = abbrev
}

% class `nomencl': nomenclature
\DeclareAcronym{angelsperarea}{
  short = \ensuremath{a} ,
  long  = The number of angels per unit area ,
  sort  = a ,
  class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{numofangels}{
  short = \ensuremath{N} ,
  long  = The number of angels per needle point ,
  sort  = N ,
  class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{areaofneedle}{
  short = \ensuremath{A} ,
  long  = The area of the needle point ,
  sort  = A ,
  class = nomencl ,
  cite =  ,
}

\begin{document}

\ac{ny}, \ac{la} \ac{ny} and \ac{un} are abbreviations whereas
\ac{angelsperarea}, \ac{numofangels} and \ac{areaofneedle} are part of the
nomenclature

\printacronyms

\printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

## Update Further problem (Solved)

I have implemented the wrapped labeling environment and it looks perfect, however I want to print the acronyms irrespective of whether I use them or not, so I changed the `\acsetup{list-type=acronyms,only-used=false}` command as shown. The problem is that now I only get a maximum of 4 acronyms in each print list, this does **not** happen however if I simply `\printacronyms`. Could you help make sense of this please?

Please find updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{acro}

% \DeclareAcronym{ny}{
% short = NY ,
% short-plural = ,
% long = New York ,
% long-plural = ,
% class = city ,
% cite = NewYork
% }

\DeclareAcronym{pwr}{
    short = PWR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Pressurised Water Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactors ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{ebr}{
    short = EBR-I ,
    short-plural =  ,
    long = Experimental Breeder Reactor I ,
    long-plural =  ,
    class = reac.exist ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{lwr}{
    short = LWR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Light Water Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactors ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{epr}{
    short = EPR ,
    short-plural =  ,
    long = European Pressurised Reactor ,
    long-plural =  ,
    class = reac.exist ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{candu}{
    short = CANDU ,
    short-plural =  ,
    long = CANada Deuterium Uranium ,
    long-plural =  ,
    class = reac.exist ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{acr}{
    short = ACR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Advanced CANDU Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactors ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{sfr}{
    short = SFR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Sodium Fast Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{lfr}{
    short = LFR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Lead Fast Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactors ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{gfr}{
    short = GFR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Gas Fast Reactors ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{msr}{
    short = MSR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Molten Salt Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{scwr}{
    short = SCWR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Supercritical Water Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{vhtr}{
    short = VHTR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Very High Temperature Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{htgr}{
    short = HTGR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = High Temperature Gas cooled Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{htr}{
    short = HTR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = High Temperature Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{mhr}{
    short = GT-MHR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Gas Turbine-Modular Helium Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{pmr}{
    short = PMR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Prismatic Modular Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{pbmr}{
    short = PBMR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Pebble Bed Modular Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{heu}{
    short = HEU ,
    short-plural =  ,
    long = High Enriched Uranium ,
    long-plural =  ,
    class = reac.term ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{leu}{
    short = LEU ,
    short-plural =  ,
    long = Low Enriched Uranium ,
    long-plural =  ,
    class = reac.term ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{pcs}{
    short = PCS ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Power Conversion System ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reac.term ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{ihx}{
    short = IHX ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Intermediate Heat Exchanger ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reac.term ,
}


\newenvironment{acronyms}
  {\labeling[~\dots]{myheadings}}
  {\endlabeling}

\acsetup{list-type=acronyms,only-used=false}

\begin{document}

\addchap*{List of Acronyms}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms}

    \printacronyms[include-classes=reactors,name=Reactor Types]
    \printacronyms[include-classes=reac.exist,name=Reactor Names]
    \printacronyms[include-classes=reac.term,name=Reactor Terms]


\end{document}
```

## Solved

Turns out that putting an extra `s` for the `class name` (`\printacronyms[include-classes=reactors,name=Reactor Types]`) for reactor causes this error. The class was simply called `reactor`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use KOMA-Script's `labeling` environment as underlying list environment. The syntax is

```
\begin{labeling}[<separator>]{<longest item>}
  \item[<item>] ...
  \item[<item>] ...
\end{labeling}
```

In order to use it you have to wrap it in an environment *without* arguments and tell `acro` to use it with the `list-type` option:

```
\newenvironment{acronyms}
  {\labeling[--]{thelongestword}}
  {\endlabeling}
\acsetup{list-type=acronyms}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{acro}

% class `abbrev': abbreviations:
\DeclareAcronym{ny}{
  short = NY ,
  long  = New York ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{la}{
  short = LA ,
  long  = Los Angeles ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{un}{
  short = UN ,
  long  = United Nations ,
  class = abbrev
}

% class `nomencl': nomenclature
\DeclareAcronym{angelsperarea}{
  short = \ensuremath{a} ,
  long  = The number of angels per unit area ,
  sort  = a ,
  class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{numofangels}{
  short = \ensuremath{N} ,
  long  = The number of angels per needle point ,
  sort  = N ,
  class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{areaofneedle}{
  short = \ensuremath{A} ,
  long  = The area of the needle point ,
  sort  = A ,
  class = nomencl
}

\newenvironment{acronyms}
  {\labeling[--]{thelongestword}}
  {\endlabeling}
\acsetup{list-type=acronyms}

\begin{document}

\ac{ny}, \ac{la} \ac{ny} and \ac{un} are abbreviations whereas
\ac{angelsperarea}, \ac{numofangels} and \ac{areaofneedle} are part of the
nomenclature

\printacronyms[exclude-classes=nomencl]

\printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello again, thanks for the help you offered, it seems that when I use the command `\printacronyms[include-classes=reac.exist,name=Reactor Names]` it only prints 4 acronyms on the list, however if I only `\printacronyms` it prints all of them, would you know why this could be? Thank you

Comment: Solved it was something infinitely silly but which gave a strange output result

Comment: @cgnider I have almost the same case, using a `KOMA-script's` class (`scrbook` in my case) with the `acro` package, I made the lists of acronyms and all is OK but how to add those lists at the `toc`?

Comment: @Aradnix with KOMA-Script you could for example set `acro`'s option `list-heading=addsec` (you know KOMA-Script's command `\addsec` I guess?)